# Mongo filter into GraphQL query | must be an object, got _String_

Tags: javascript, mongodb, graphql

There's a way to pass a filter option to Mongo via GraphQL? because I tried this way but I had an error 
`"message": "Parameter \"filter\" to find() must be an object, got {email: \"test@test.com\"}",`

This is my query type

```
users: {
      type: new GraphQLList(UserType),
      args: {
        filter: { type: GraphQLString }
      },
      resolve(_, { filter }, { req, res }) {
        // I tried several ways to get query string and give it to mongo into a object
        JSONFilter = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(filter));
        return UserSchema.find(JSONFilter);
      }
    }
```

and my query looks like this

```
query myReferrals {
  users(filter: "{email: \"test@test.com\"}"){ //I though this should be enough, but no!
    referrals{
      user{
        email
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It was a "typo", on my query should be this way:

```
query myReferrals {
  users(filter: "{\"email\": \"test@test.com\"}"){ // Just Add `\"key\"` to key
    referrals{
      user{
        email
      }
    }
  }
}
```